# How to remove file from dragzone.js

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, dropzone.js

I used Dropzone.js; file is uploaded, but how to remove unwanted file from save popup box?

[image]

How to remove file from dragzone.js?

Comment: display image; grammar corrected

Comment: What sir i can't get your point

Comment: Don't worry, this was just how I edited your post in the "Help and Improvement" queue; the system fails to automatically add a note about this.